# Java and Maven keep resetting from ~/.profile

Tags: java, linux, maven, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu machine with Java and Maven both installed. However, whenever I run `java -version` I keep getting

```
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install default-jre            
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

And whenever I run `mvn -version` I get

```
Command 'mvn' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install maven
```

I've literally tried everything, from adding additional lines in  `~/.profile` to adding the same lines in `/etc/environment`.

Now, look what I do (in a new terminal):

1. `java -version`
2. `mvn -version`
3. `sudo nano ~/.profile`
4. `source ~/.profile`
5. `java -version`
6. `mvn -version`

The output:

1. Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install default-jre
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless

2. Command 'mvn' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install maven

3. No output
4. No output
5. java version "1.8.0_211"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
6. Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-05T00:00:29+05:00)
   Maven home: /home/alex/apache-maven-3.6.1
   Java version: 1.8.0_211, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/jre
   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
   OS name: "linux", version: "5.0.0-31-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

I have no idea why this happens. So, whenever I open a new terminal and try to do something as simple as running a java program I have to do it over and over again.

The lines I've added are (although they've always existed)

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
export M2_HOME=/home/alex/apache-maven-3.6.1
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
```

What's the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend using [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/) to manage different JDK versions.

Comment: Run `bash -l -x` in a new terminal and see where the variables are being. It could be that something in your setup unsets them. Also recommending SDKMAN.

Comment: why do you add two line: JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211 and export JAVA_HOME instead one line export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211 ?

Comment: Did you edit other config files like ~/.bashrc; /etc/profile; /etc/environment and others?

Answer (score 1):

When you define `PATH=$M2:$PATH`, the variable `M2` is nmot yet defined. `export PATH=$M2:$PATH` should be define **after** `export M2=$M2_HOME/bin`, not before.